# Query an array with Atlas $search

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

As inputs, I get a search query (`should` operator) and a filter (about whether or not a post is liked, `must`/`mustNot` operators).
I start with the following as a foundation to my aggregation pipeline:

```js
{ $search: { compound: {} } }
```

Then, if a query is given, I add this:

```js
$search.compound.should.push({
    text: {
        query: q,
        path: ["data.displayName"],
        score: {
            boost: {
                value: 5,
            },
        },
    },
    // Plus others
});
```

Now, every post has a `likes` array. I would like to only select the posts that include a particular string in their `likes`, if possible under `compound.must`/`mustNot`.

I'd like to avoid loading the data on the computer and filtering the documents locally (*I pay for the entire database, I use the entire database!*). If array manipulation is impossible in Aggregation Pipelines, what could an alternative be? I'm still pretty confused by the docs, and where operators should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You are so close. In the way you have structured the query, what you need is `compound.filter`. You can have must clauses as well. It will exclude documents that don't contain the string. See here

```
$search.compound.must.push({
    text: {
        query: q,
        path: ["data.likes"],
    },
    // Plus others
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I may have not been clear enough: I think I've understood how to add layers to my search, but I don't know how to check if an array contains a value, in the same way, that `text` checks for text in a string.

Comment: check out my edit. Thanks for the clarification @a2br

Comment: The code indicates if a path exists, not if the array contains a value... Or am I missing something here?

Comment: the first query was if the array contained a string value. But I thought it was a matter of semantics because some of your comment was not exactly using the terminology in the expected sense. So, I thought maybe you meant by array, the single value array that is your path.

Comment: I think I need further clarification.

Comment: The `likes` field is an array of strings. I need to know, in the aggregation pipeline, if that array includes a particular string.